# Using QBWC 2.0 to sync QB files

Tags: quickbooks

I've just begun to read the QB Developer documentation and have come to the conclusion that to write a web-enabled application that will sync/remote backup QB files between two machines over the Internet, that the QBWC is the 'approved' way to accomplish this task. The .NET application samples in the QB SDK (V12) are not using WCF but WSDL and SOAP.

But before I commit to going that route, I am asking if anyone has a better approach. I'd prefer to use WCF and MS Sync Framework, but I don't want to head down that road if it will mean using a cannon to kill a mosquito.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You really hinted at two separate goals here, so I'll address each specifically:

> ... remote backup QB files between two machines ...

If your goal is *BACKUP* then the Web Connector is certainly not the answer. The purpose of the Web Connector is to enable *integration* between QuickBooks and web applications, via the QuickBooks API/SDK. Since not all data stored within QuickBooks is accessible via the API, the Web Connector *is not appropriate for backup*. It is impossible to get a complete, accurate backup of the entire QuickBooks data set via the Web Connector.

On the other hand...

> ... web-enabled application that will sync ...

If your goal is to allow integration/sync of data between your web app and QuickBooks, the Web Connector is a decent solution. Yes, it uses SOAP (with a grand total of only about 5 very simple methods). No, you can't use WCF/anything else without writing your own version of the Web Connector.

If you add more details about specifically what you're looking to do with specifically what data, you'll probably get some better answers and suggestions about approach.